# Problem with Serialize/Deserialize objects to/from XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml-serialization

I have to first deserialize xml file to List then enlarge this list and serialize all with add 1 object more (magnification is needed for this)

code from XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <name>Danie</name>
           <lastName>McJackie</lastName>
           <age>27</age>
 </Person>
```

code from .cs file: I commented where i got error and copy the error message

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Xml;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {

   }
   private List<Person> Deserialize(string path)
   {
       using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
       {
           XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
           return (List<Person>)ser.Deserialize(fs);
           //There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
           // I got this error and don't know how to manage with it.
       }
   }

   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       string path = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/test.xml");
       List<Person> people = File.Exists(path) ? Deserialize(path) :new List<Person>();
       people.Add(new Person(TextBox1.Text, TextBox2.Text, int.Parse(TextBox3.Text)));
       using (FileStream fs = File.OpenWrite(path))
       {
           XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
           ser.Serialize(fs, people);
       }


   }
}
```

and at least class to serialize:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;



[Serializable]
public class Person
{

   public string name;
   public string lastName;
   public int age;
   public Person(string _name, string _lastName, int _age)
   {
       name = _name;
       lastName = _lastName;
       age = _age;
   }
   public Person()
   {

   }
}
```

exception details:

```
System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled by user code
Message=There is an error in XML document (2, 2).
Source=System.Xml
StackTrace:
      at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(XmlReader xmlReader,                                             String    encodingStyle, XmlDeserializationEvents events)
   at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.Deserialize(Stream stream)
   at _Default.Deserialize(String path) in e:\Programy c#\WebSites\ASP8\Default.aspx.cs:line 22
   at _Default.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in e:\Programy c#\WebSites\ASP8\Default.aspx.cs:line 29
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
   at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
       at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)                
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean                                                                includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint,       Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.InvalidOperationException
       Message=<Person xmlns=''> was not expected.
   Source=_1r-cm1p
   StackTrace:
        at Microsoft.Xml.Serialization.GeneratedAssembly.XmlSerializationReaderList1.Read3_ArrayOfPerson()
   InnerException:
```

**This is what i added with last edit**

Deserialize file .cs:

```
string path = Server.MapPath(Request.ApplicationPath + "/test.xml");
    using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
    {
        XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
        List<Person> os = (List<Person>)ser.Deserialize(fs);
        foreach (var i in os)
        {
            Label1.Text += i.Name + "<hr />" + i.LastName + "<hr />" + i.Age.ToString() + "<hr />";
        }

        fs.Close();
```

everything work fine thanks everyone for help:)

Comment: What is the error? Exception details?

Comment: just a helper - change your naming conventions slightly _name should be your private members, and your public string name should be public string Name (note capitalization)

Comment: Error at 2,2 almost always means a carriage return at the start of the file - is this the case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Person>));
```

Try

```
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
```

Comment: when i changed i get error:

Unable to cast object of type 'Person' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Person]'.

Comment: But it's now working. Just adjust your code cause it's returning a single Person.

Comment: Sorry, i see you are serializing the Person list, so your XML should have more than one person, right?

Comment: Then something is wrong cause your XML is of type Person and should be of type ArrayOfPerson

Comment: yes i did . is it any problem?;> when i had delete file then nothing happend when i clicked button

Comment: If you write a XML of type Person, you read with a deserializer of type Person. If you write of type List<Person>, you read with List<Person>. You can't interchange.

Comment: oh then i will deserialize type of Person but how to add next Person to the same XML file?

Comment: the XML of type person you have is wrong. throw it away and start over only with List<Person>

Answer (score 0):

Is there a line end in your namespace specifier?

```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://
www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

should be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Person xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
```

When copied from the question, the line end seems to be there

Comment: what u mean? sry but i don't understand

Comment: I hope you _do_ see the difference in the two snippets?